# Calling Functions in QZ-Print Java Applet doesn't work in PHP

Tags: javascript, java, php, printing, applet

i'm trying use a Java plugin to print to raw print to a ticket printer from a browser. I've written a test program in HTML and Javascript which is working ok, but now i'm trying to transfer the code to a php script for printing tickets in a bigger app. I'm gettting this kind of error in firefox debug whenever i call a function from the app. "**TypeError: qz.findPrinter is not a function**".

I changed the extension on the original test program to .php from .html and i'm recieving error there too now.

Any functions from the the java begin with "qz."

Here's the plugin for reference
https://code.google.com/p/jzebra/wiki/TutorialWebApplet

I figure it's something i don't know about php as it works ok as a .html file but I've included the whole script anyway. The php is running from xampp.

Thank you for you time.

```
<html>

<head><title>Receipt Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
deployQZ();

function deployQZ() {
    var attributes = {id: "qz", code:'qz.PrintApplet.class', 
        archive:'qz-print.jar', width:1, height:1};
    var parameters = {jnlp_href: 'qz-print_jnlp.jnlp', 
        cache_option:'plugin', disable_logging:'false', 
        initial_focus:'false'};
    if (deployJava.versionCheck("1.7+") == true) {}
    else if (deployJava.versionCheck("1.6+") == true) {
        attributes['archive'] = 'jre6/qz-print.jar';
        parameters['jnlp_href'] = 'jre6/qz-print_jnlp.jnlp';
    }
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.5');
}

function countSpace(product, price, section)    {
var spaceNeeded = (section - product.length - price.toString().length);
var spaces = "";
for(i=0; i < spaceNeeded; i++) {
spaces += " ";
    }
return (product + spaces + price);  
}

function findPrinter() {
     // Searches for locally installed printer with "zebra" in the name
     qz.findPrinter("zebra");


     // Hint:  Carriage Return = \r, New Line = \n, Escape Double Quotes= \"


    var ticketTime = new Date();    
    var singleLine = "\n------------------------------------------\n";
    var doubleLine = "\n==========================================\n";
    var product = ["Mirdan Tuzlama", "Suckuklu Pide" ];
    var price = [8.00, 8.00];
    var prodCharLength = 37;
    var finCharLength = 42;
    var subTotal = {name:"Subtotal", value:0};

    for(i=0;i<product.length;i++) {
    subTotal.value += price[i];
    } 

    var tax = {name:"Tax", value:((20/100)*subTotal.value)};
    var total = {name:"Total", value:(subTotal.value-tax.value)}; 
    var ticketEnd = "                Thank You\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
    var productSec = "";
    tax.value = 0 - tax.value;
    for(j=0;j<product.length;j++) {
    var priceloop = price[i];
    productSec += (" - 1 " + countSpace(product[j], price[j],prodCharLength));
        if (j<=(product.length-2)){
        productSec += "\n"
        }
    }


    qz.append("\nDate:" + ticketTime.getDate() + "/" 
                        + (ticketTime.getMonth()+1) + "/" 
                        + ticketTime.getFullYear() 
            + "\nTime:" + ticketTime.getHours() + ":" 
                        + ticketTime.getMinutes() 
            + "\nTable: B10\nTicket No:2"               
            //+ singleLine + " - 1 " + product1 +"                   8.00\n - 1 " + product1 +"                    8:00" 
            + singleLine + productSec
            + doubleLine + countSpace(subTotal.name, subTotal.value,finCharLength) 
            + '\n' + countSpace(tax.name, tax.value,finCharLength)
            + '\n' + countSpace(total.name, total.value,finCharLength)              
            + doubleLine + ticketEnd);

    qz.print(); 

}
</script>

<body>

<input type="button" onClick="findPrinter()" value="Print ESCP" /><br />
</body>
```

Comment: This example does not have any PHP in it.  Can you clarify the problem please?  QZ Print uses a JavaScript API and JavaScript runs on the client whereas PHP runs on the server.  Mixing the two requires a much better understand of these technologies which is outside of the scope of the software API or usage.  We have two php examples available here: https://github.com/qzind/qz-print/wiki/raw-printing#using-echo

Answer (score 0):

> "TypeError: qz.findPrinter is not a function"

- In QZ "Tray" 1.9 (desktop Application), `qz.findPrinter(...)` is defined as a `preemptive` function, [created by `qz-websocket.js`](https://github.com/qzind/qz-print/blob/1.9/js/qz-websocket.js) and must be included in your project to be exposed.  
  **If you didn't include `qz-websocket.js`, this message will occur.**
- In QZ "Print" 1.9 (Java Applet) and older, `qz.findPRinter(...)` was exposed through a Java Applet using Java LiveConnect calls, so this was a sign the applet did not load. 
  **If your applet did not load properly, this message will occur.**

**Note:** 1.9 was capable of behaving as both a desktop application AND a Java applet.

**Deprecation warning:** 1.9 and older are [EOL](https://qz.io/wiki/Roadmap).  QZ Tray 2.0 and higher, the API has changed significantly.  A migration guide is [available](https://qz.io/wiki/2.0-getting-started#migration-guide).